# Manga available in the states where a talking wolf raises a spirit reincarnated as a black fox cub

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I am looking for this manga.  I cannot find its name!  The premise is that a warlord or magician (I forget!) comes back to life as a black fox cub.  It has beautiful watercolor painted covers and has a motherly sort of wolf caring for this fox, trying to keep him well behaved.

I know it's *not* *My Fox Demon Cub is also well-behaved Today*, as that has a human child who has nine demon fox tails.  This story I'm thinking about is mostly animal focused.

I think it's distributed by VIZ or one of those companies who release English translations of manga.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this? And was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: This was black and white and I saw it in a Barnes and Noble in the US in the last year or two.  It had normal colorized covers and first page or two and was available in trade paperbacks.

Answer (score 3):

I have found it! [*The Fox & Little Tanuki*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/50351461)

> [image]
>
> It is said that there are some special animals occasionally born with great powers. Senzou the black fox is one of those... but instead of using his powers for good, he abused his strength until the Sun Goddess imprisoned him for his bad behavior.
>
> Three hundred years later, he's finally been released, but only on one condition — he can't have any of his abilities back until he successfully helps a tanuki cub named Manpachi become an assistant to the gods. Unfortunately for Senzou, there's no cheating when it comes to completing his task! The magic beads around his neck make sure he can't wander too far from his charge or ignore his duties, and so... Senzou the once-great Fox Spirit must figure out how to be an actually-great babysitter to an innocent little tanuki or risk being stuck without his powers forever!

And it was distributed in the US by **Tokyopop**, not Viz!

Comment: You will be able to self accept in about 44 hours. :) Please don't forget to do so.